# Where can I find lifecycleMappingMetadata schema?

Tags: maven-3, m2eclipse

In eclipse:

To correct *"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration..."* problem, I choose to create my `lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml` instead of pollute my pom with IDE concerns.

I manage to write this file with example, but I can't find a xsd or DTD for `lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml`. Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical [`lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/89cd40ba907e178d523f40ac22f7eac0291de37b/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml) file in the [**`eclipse/m2e-core`**](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core) repo comes without an xsd reference.

But in that same m2e repo, you also have a [`org.eclipse.m2e.core/mdo/lifecycle-mapping-metadata-model.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/89cd40ba907e178d523f40ac22f7eac0291de37b/org.eclipse.m2e.core/mdo/lifecycle-mapping-metadata-model.xml) which helps to validate that xml file. It is used as a [model in the main `pom.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/c9e38071f13d784dcf36f32f90b0e017752aa40e/org.eclipse.m2e.core/pom.xml#L51), when used by the [`modello-maven-plugin`](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/modello/modello-maven-plugin/).